# Failed to load SQL in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Not able to see SQL dashboard in Google Cloud Platform. When clicking on SQL link, getting the below error.

[image: GCP SQL error]

Any idea why it's happening and how to fix it ??

Comment: I have seen this happen, but I am not sure what this issue is. Refreshing the page in the browser solves it.

Comment: Refreshing the page is also not solving the issue. Even I have enabled the SQL admin and sql api also. Still no luck.

Comment: Reboot your system and try again. Otherwise my only suggestion is to open a support ticket with Google Support and give them the Tracking Number for the error. There is no information in your question that can help us inform you of the real problem.

Answer (score 1):

Got the solution from google like 'it's browser issue'. In crome its not working. But in other browser(eg firefox, IE) its working.

Answer (score 0):

This message can appear for a number of reasons. It could be an intermittent issue or something wrong with your account settings. To troubleshoot do the following steps in order:

- Try to open the page in incognito mode of your browser
- Check your permissions in IAM
- If the issue persists, open a new private case on Issue Tracker mentioning your project-id by clicking [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=491274&template=1161130)

Comment: Thank you @Omar. I tried few options like refreshed the page, created the IAM roles, enabled SQL admin API and SQL api but still no luck. So i have created the private case and waiting for response.

Answer (score 0):

Today this error really annoys so much, comes again and again and only come in the `SQL` instance, every other thing works fine But in the end, I try to login into `Incognito` mode and then its work so please try in the `incognito` mode or else try in a different browser.